# What are these strange issues when scraping a web page, maybe encoding?

Tags: ruby, curl, web-scraping, web-crawler, nokogiri

I'm trying to parse some web pages such as these:

```
http://www.imovirtual.com/imoveis/apartamentos/t0-t1-entrecampos-mobilado-lisboa/1038329/
http://www.imovirtual.com/imoveis/apartamentos/t2-quinta-do-romao-quarteira/1156717/
```

I'm using Nokogiri::HTML, and with the first link all is OK, but with the second I only get trash and it's impossible to parse.

I tried using `curl`, and the result is the same.
Here is a sample of the result for the second link:

```
��� DG;v�u�G{f�
                     ��;?�@ː0t�Yw���`~�d��
f9����:�}P2k�㤷ϓ���togg���B�D�j���P�AS���cV���5h+�dp
```

What can be the problem?
Both pages render nicely in a browser, and I can't find significant differences in their DOM.

Note: using `wget` on the second link results in an unreadable file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The webpage is compressed, check the header: **Content-Encoding: gzip**
You need to decompress it.

Edit:

If you are using ruby try this:

```
cleanHtml = Zlib::GzipReader.new(StringIO.new(htmlCompressed)).read
```

Comment: Most likely the OP is using OpenURI, so that should probably be: `Zlib::GzipReader.new(open(url_to_resource)).read`

Comment: It works! You know of a way to figure out if its compressed or not?

Comment: I ended up with:
`page = Zlib::GzipReader.new(page) if page.content_encoding.include? "gzip"`

Also found out that you can use `curl -I` to get the header of response. @walfire @the-tin-man